# How to ssh to servers internally by hostname without domain name?

Tags: ssh, networking

I need to log into multiple servers at work to get my work done.  I'm getting tired of typing the FQDN of a server to access.  I'm logging in/out via ssh on our own private network.  I'm 99% sure it's on our own private network b/c all the servers have ip addr 10.x.y.z.  Is there a way to ssh into servers with just the hostname and not the domain name?

We have servers in multiple countries.  The way our servers are named is very long.  It is named as follows:

`hostname.country.domainname.com`

I am getting carpal tunnel typing in
`ssh me@hostname1.country.domainname.com`

... every time I access one of our servers.  If I'm in the US and I try to access another host that's in the US, I can just type `ssh me@hostname2` and I connect fine.  However, if I'm in the US and try to connect to a server in England, I can't type `ssh me@hostname3.eng` and connect to `hostname3`.

The workaround I did was setup an alias in my ~/.ssh/config file for some of the servers.  However, I don't think it's feasible to add 1000+ servers into that file.  I've already added 20+ servers and my co-workers think I'm crazy, although I think they are crazy for typing the FQDN when sshing around.

Is there an easy way for us to set up something so that we don't have to type in our domainname.com each time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can wildcard and use `%h` in your config

eg

```
Host *.eng
  Hostname %h.domainname.com
```

Now when you do `ssh foo.eng` it will try to connect to `foo.eng.domainname.com`.

You can add other options to this config as well; eg forcing the username

```
Host *.eng
  Hostname %h.domainname.com
  User me
```

Now when you do `ssh foo.eng` it will try to connect to `foo.eng.domainname.com` as the user `me`.

```
% ssh foo.eng
ssh: Could not resolve hostname foo.eng.domainname.com: Name or service not known
```

(well, obviously I get an error before it's not a valid hostname for me!)

So now you only need one rule per country.

Comment: My first thought was DNS aliases, the second was hosts file, but I missed that there's multiple servers.  This solution looks excellent.  What config gets the line(s) you've posted?

Comment: This goes into `$HOME/.ssh/config` or you can make it system wide in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: Does it work with `user@*.eng`?

Comment: With the rule I wrote you can do `ssh foobar@somewhere.eng` and it will work as expected.  All this does is rewrite the hostname component.  It'll even work with `scp` and `sftp` and so on.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the `CanonicalDomains` option in your ssh config.

Adding the following to your ssh config file will make ssh try to append `domainname.com` to any host that has at most 1 dot in its name :

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains domainname.com
```

With this config `ssh foo.eng` will first try `foo.eng.domainname.com`, and fallback to `foo.eng` if the host cannot be found. Likewise, `ssh github.com` will first try `github.com.domainname.com`, so if you want to connect to GitHub, your DNS server should not return records for non existing hosts.

The `CanonicalizeMaxDots` can be used to control how many dots can appear in the hostname before ssh considers it fully qualified and doesn't append `domainname.com`. it defaults to 1 which should be enough for you given the scheme you currently have, but if you ever get to something like `hostname.city.country` you would need to increase it.

Answer (score 10):

If you add

```
search domainname.com
```

to `/etc/resolv.conf`, and use `hostname.country`, `ssh` (and other network programs, for that matter) will automatically append `domainname.com` for you<sup>1</sup>.

I don't think adding the different country domains to your `search` path is a good idea because you may get unexpected behavior if two servers in two different countries share the same hostname<sup>2</sup>

I believe this method is better than changing the `ssh` configuration because this allows `hostname.country` to resolve regardless of the program you're using (`telnet`, VNC,...).

See [`resolv.conf(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf)

---

<sup>1</sup> More accurately, it will append `domainname.com` if it can't resolve `hostname.country` by itself.

<sup>2</sup> In such a scenario `hostname` will resolve to the server in the country whose domain is listed first in the `search` path.

Comment: BTW you can also do this as non-root and per process by env variable LOCALDOMAIN. `man resolv.conf`

Comment: This works to resolve the SSH host, but if you're using GSS/Kerberos the names won't match and authing will fail.